# R ave by columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to use the `ave` function on many columns (tens) on the data frame:

```
ave(df[,the_cols], df[,c('site', 'month')], FUN = mean)
```

The problem is that `ave` runs the `mean` function on all `the_cols` columns together. Is there any way to run it for each of `the_cols` columns separately?

I tried to look at the other functions. `tapply` and `aggregate` are different, they return only one row per group. I need the `ave` behaviour, i.e. to return the same number of rows as given in the original `df`. There is also a `by` function, but using it would be very clumsy as it returns a complicated list structure that would have to be converted somehow.

Certainly many clumsy and ugly (by & do.call, multiple *apply function calls etc.) solutions exist but is there some really easy and elegant?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps I'm missing something, but an `apply()` approach here would work very well and wouldn't be ugly or require any ugly hacks. Some dummy data:

```
df <- data.frame(A = rnorm(20), B = rnorm(20), site = gl(5,4), month = gl(10, 2))
```

what is wrong with:

```
sapply(df[, c("A","B")], ave, df$site, df$month)
```

? Coerce that to a data frame via `data.frame()` if you really want that.

```
R> sapply(df[, c("A","B")], ave, df$site, df$month)
            A        B
 [1,]  0.0775  0.04845
 [2,]  0.0775  0.04845
 [3,] -1.5563  0.43443
 [4,] -1.5563  0.43443
 [5,]  0.7193  0.01151
 [6,]  0.7193  0.01151
 [7,] -0.9243 -0.28483
 [8,] -0.9243 -0.28483
 [9,]  0.3316  0.14473
[10,]  0.3316  0.14473
[11,] -0.2539  0.20384
[12,] -0.2539  0.20384
[13,]  0.5558 -0.37239
[14,]  0.5558 -0.37239
[15,]  0.1976 -0.22693
[16,]  0.1976 -0.22693
[17,]  0.2031  1.11041
[18,]  0.2031  1.11041
[19,]  0.3229 -0.53818
[20,]  0.3229 -0.53818
```

Putting it together a bit more, how about

```
AVE <- function(df, cols, ...) {
  dots <- list(...)
  out <- sapply(df[, cols], ave, ...)
  out <- data.frame(as.data.frame(dots), out)
  names(out) <- c(paste0("Fac", seq_along(dots)), cols)
  out
}

R> AVE(df, c("A","B"), df$site, df$month)
   Fac1 Fac2       A        B
1     1    1  0.0775  0.04845
2     1    1  0.0775  0.04845
3     1    2 -1.5563  0.43443
4     1    2 -1.5563  0.43443
5     2    3  0.7193  0.01151
6     2    3  0.7193  0.01151
7     2    4 -0.9243 -0.28483
8     2    4 -0.9243 -0.28483
9     3    5  0.3316  0.14473
10    3    5  0.3316  0.14473
11    3    6 -0.2539  0.20384
12    3    6 -0.2539  0.20384
13    4    7  0.5558 -0.37239
14    4    7  0.5558 -0.37239
15    4    8  0.1976 -0.22693
16    4    8  0.1976 -0.22693
17    5    9  0.2031  1.11041
18    5    9  0.2031  1.11041
19    5   10  0.3229 -0.53818
20    5   10  0.3229 -0.53818
```

The details of working with `...` escape me at the moment, but you should be able to get better names for the `Fac1` etc that I used here.

I'll throw an alternative representation out there for you: `aggregate()` but use the `ave()` function instead of `mean()`:

```
R> aggregate(cbind(A, B) ~ site + month, data = df, ave)
   site month     A.1     A.2      B.1      B.2
1     1     1  0.0775  0.0775  0.04845  0.04845
2     1     2 -1.5563 -1.5563  0.43443  0.43443
3     2     3  0.7193  0.7193  0.01151  0.01151
4     2     4 -0.9243 -0.9243 -0.28483 -0.28483
5     3     5  0.3316  0.3316  0.14473  0.14473
6     3     6 -0.2539 -0.2539  0.20384  0.20384
7     4     7  0.5558  0.5558 -0.37239 -0.37239
8     4     8  0.1976  0.1976 -0.22693 -0.22693
9     5     9  0.2031  0.2031  1.11041  1.11041
10    5    10  0.3229  0.3229 -0.53818 -0.53818
```

Note quite the stated output, but it is something that is simple to reshape if needed.

Comment: Wow, the `sapply` one-liner is simple and works great, thanks!! I wouldn't have this idea to run `ave` in `sapply`, amazing codegolf :-) Hate your `AVE` function though. Why do it when such a beautiful one-liner exists?

Comment: If you wanted the `site` & `month` info and had to do this a lot, I'd quickly write a wrapper like this to do it for me. If you don't need the factors bolted on, just use the one-liner.

Comment: Aha, now I see: that's just to bundle the site&month with the results... BTW, isn't it better to use `cbind` in your `AVE` function for that? I guess then the `names()<-` stuff won't be needed.

Comment: Thank you for the alternative `aggregate` solution. Does it create one column for each record within group? Seems nasty :) What if the groups don't have the same number of records?

Comment: Yes, is suppose it would pop up an `NA`. Haven't checked. Try it and feedback...?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to have a data.frame back

```
library(plyr)
## assuming that the_cols are string
## if col index just add the index of site and month
the_cols <- c("site", "month", the_cols)
ddply(df, c('site', 'month'), FUN = numcolwise(mean))[,the_cols]
```

Comment: I always prefer to get by with base libraries only, but thanks for `plyr` solution!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `by` with `colMeans`

```
by(df[,the_cols], df[,c('site', 'month')], FUN = colMeans)
```

You can also use `ave` inside `lapply`:

```
res <- lapply(df[,the_cols], function(x) 
                               ave(x, df[,c('site', 'month')], FUN = mean))

data.frame(res) # create data frame
```

Comment: as I stated in the question, `by` doesn't return a `data.frame`! Requires a lot of ugly code to get it back to the original structure! See my question

Comment: @Tomas The function `ave` doesn't return a data frame either.