# Ratio Month to Annual Average

Tags: r, apply, dplyr

Trying to convert this data-frame into a ratio matrix such that for Jan 2007 column A,  it would be  equal to Jan 2007/Average of Year 2007, for Feb 2007  it would be equal to 4/Average of Year 2007...need to apply it across all columns.

```
YearM   A B C
2007/Jan    3 5 7
2007/Feb    4 5 6
2007/Mar    4 4 2
...........
2013/Dec    4 4 2
```

Comment: could you use `dput` to post a sample of your data? the sample you have inserted now is very difficult to work with

Comment: just figured out how to use dput.

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer that you find the most helpful by clicking on the grey check mark under the downvote button

Answer (score 2):

```
library(dplyr)

avg_mat = df %>%
  group_by(year = sub("/.*", "", YearM)) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(A:C), "mean") %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(A:C)  %>%
  as.matrix()

mat = df %>%
  select(A:C) %>%
  as.matrix() 

cbind(YearM = df$YearM, as.data.frame(mat/avg_mat))
```

**Result:**

```
     YearM         A         B   C
1 2007/Jan 0.8181818 1.0714286 1.4
2 2007/Feb 1.0909091 1.0714286 1.2
3 2007/Mar 1.0909091 0.8571429 0.4
4 2013/Dec 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0
```

**Data:**

```
df = read.table(text = "YearM   A B C
2007/Jan    3 5 7
2007/Feb    4 5 6
2007/Mar    4 4 2
2013/Dec    4 4 2", header = TRUE)
```

Comment: thanks! any way to add the dates/month back to the output matrix?

Comment: @jkl Sure, see my updates. To add the `YearM`, you have to convert the matrix to data.frame, otherwise it will be coerced to numeric.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way using the `sapply` and `ave` functions. The `ave` part is borrowed from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21340837/5619526).

```
df$year <- year = sub("/.*", "", df$YearM)    
df[,c('A','B','C')] <- df[,c('A','B','C')] / sapply(df[,c('A','B','C')], ave, df$year)


     YearM         A         B   C year
1 2007/Jan 0.8181818 1.0714286 1.4 2007
2 2007/Feb 1.0909091 1.0714286 1.2 2007
3 2007/Mar 1.0909091 0.8571429 0.4 2007
4 2013/Dec 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0 2013
```